# Xcode side-by-side install. Is it fine to use?

Tags: xcode

Xcode offers side-by-side install. However, I haven't tried it but now I'm being pressured to test the new beta SDK (for future projects) while keeping my current SDK environment (for current production). So I'm considering a side-by-side install.

Currently Xcode 4 is not stable enough, but before to install, I want to know possible issues with a side-by-side installation. I'm preparing Xcode 3.x (legacy) and Xcode 4.2 (beta) addition to current 4.0.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have any difficulties. I've been running side-by-side installations of Xcode for years now, no problems.

Helpful hint: Modify the icons for the different Xcode installations to differentiate between SDK versions. Mixing up beta and production environments has caused issues for me in the past.  [Cached link to my post on the subject](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3avpbOxj1ZjJ4J%3anothing2fancy.com/2010/09/25/changing-the-xcode-icon/%20xcode%20icon&cd=11&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com), since my blog is currently down.

Comment: Does your issue caused by confusing of them or side-by-side installation itself?

Comment: Confusing them. I was working in the Beta OS but thought I was working in the production OS.